# How to filter blanks in a table using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I want to copy down filter formula using Arrayformula. I also gave a hand to copy down add-on but it's not giving required result. Here is a picture of an example sheet:

[image]

I am filtering the non blank row-wise data. As data is coming from Google Form thus want to auto replicate this formula. Copy-down add-on and ARRAYFORMULA both are giving inaccurate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following formula

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT( 
                  TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(B2:F),B2:F&"@",)&REPT(" "&"♣︎",COLUMN(B2:F)=COLUMN(F2))),"♣︎"))), 
                        "@")))
```

If on the other hand if you want to get just the **first non-blank cells in each row**, please use the following

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT( 
                  TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(B2:F),B2:F&"@",)&REPT(" "&"♣︎",COLUMN(B2:F)=COLUMN(F2))),"♣︎"))), 
                       "@")),,1)
```

*(I know they are a bit long... But they work)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)
- [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)
- [`COLUMN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373)

Comment: Thankyou for your help. But still facing an issue as this formula is returning only first value from each row. Please suggest

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFGmdKqF_TKAutJbDlkyhUoRRSl_zxxnfFa9WErHG0o/edit?usp=sharing

@marikamitsos please find the attached sheet for your reference

Comment: **Sorry. My mistake**. Check the updated answer and think positive. You can 2 answers for just 1 question :)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thankyou @marikamitsos - it's working perfectly well.